ODBC Error when running a python script in a cronjob
I have a python script that uses the odbc driver for NetSuite to access the database tables. I need to run this script everyday at a specific time. I have added this script to the crontab on a Ubuntu server.
The issue is that, the python script runs successfully when I run it manually.
But when run through the cron, it gives me the following error:
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I'm not sure what the issue is.
The bash script that is run through the crontab is as follows:
!/bin/bash
source /home/username/Documents/code/.venv/bin/activate
/home/username/Documents/code/.venv/bin/python3 /home/username/Documents/code/odbc.py

When executing the bash script manually, I am in the user directory.
username@vm:~$ pwd
/home/username
username@vm:~$ bash .testScript.sh 

Python script for reference:
import pandas as pd 
import pyodbc
import time
import config
import bridge
from datetime import datetime, date
import pandas_gbq
from google.oauth2 import service_account

# GCP Sercice Account credentials for access to BigQuery

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    '/home/username/Documents/code/service_account.json',
)

# Establish a ODBC connection

start = time.time()
conn = pyodbc.connect(config.connection_string)

cur = conn.cursor()
end = time.time(
print("Time elapsed: ", end - start)
print("Connection successful, executing query.")

# Tables to import from NetSuite

tables = ["tableName"]

# Loop through all the tables and transfer the data as-is to BigQuery. If the table already exists, replace it with the new one.


for table in tables:
    try:
        date_today = date.today()
        table_name = table
        start_time = str(datetime.now().astimezone(None).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S GMT%z"))
        print("Executing loop for table: " + table)

        sql = "select * from " + table

        start = time.time()
        print(datetime.now().astimezone(None).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S GMT%z"))

        data = pd.read_sql(sql,conn)

        end = time.time()
        print(datetime.now().astimezone(None).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S GMT%z"))
        print("Data read from NetSuite")

        
        pandas_gbq.to_gbq(constdata, "project.dataset." + table, project_id="project", if_exists='replace', credentials=credentials)

        end_time = datetime.now().astimezone(None).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S GMT%z")
        status = "Success"
        comment = ""
        bridge.statusLogger(date_today, table_name, start_time, end_time, status, comment)
    except Exception as e:
        end_time = str(datetime.now().astimezone(None).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S GMT%z"))
        status = "Error"
        comment = str(e)
        bridge.statusLogger(date_today, table_name, start_time, end_time, status, comment)

Any help is appreciated.
I have tried to check if the odbc driver is installed correctly. The driver is listed in the odbcinst.ini file. So the driver is present on the system.

Under your bash script:
/home/username/Documents/code/.venv/bin/python3 /home/username/Documents/code/odbc.py

Instead of the above code, try this:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /home/username/Documents/code/
source /home/username/Documents/code/.venv/bin/activate
python odbc.py

My assumption is that pyodbc is installed in that virtual environment.
Then you can create the crontab under the user owning that code folder and the files inside it so that you dont run into permissions issue.
